# How to round double to nearest whole number and return it as Integer

Tags: java

Let suppose that I have `double x`. I would return nearest whole number of `x`. For example:

1. if `x = 6.001` I would return `6`
2. if `x = 5.999`  I would return `6`

I suppose that I should use `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor` functions. But I don't know how return nearest whole number...

Answer (score 12):

For your example, it seems that you want to use [`Math.rint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint%28double%29).  It will return the closest integer value given a `double`.

```
int valueX = (int) Math.rint(x);
int valueY = (int) Math.rint(y);
```

Comment: Just curious, when would the round-to-even behavior for `Math.rint()` be desired?

Comment: It entirely depends on your use case.

Comment: @awksp: To get rid of sign bias, and preserve the average value of the rounded numbers. Useful when summing or averaging. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score 9):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 6.001;
    double y = 5.999;

    System.out.println(Math.round(x)); //outputs 6
    System.out.println(Math.round(y)); //outputs 6
}
```

Comment: Failing for :
`double y = 85.4999;`  
`System.out.println(Math.round(y)); //outputs 85`
Output should be 86

Comment: @AniketKulkarni Why would you expect it to output 86? The closest whole number to 85.4999 is 85. It is .4999 away from 85 and .5001 away from 86.

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = (int) Math.round(doubleVar);
```

This will round it and cast it to an int.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method you get taught in most basic computer science classes is probably to `add 0.5` (or subtract it, if your double is below 0) and simply cast it to `int`.

```
// for the simple case
double someDouble = 6.0001;
int someInt = (int) (someDouble + 0.5); 

// negative case
double negativeDouble = -5.6;
int negativeInt = (int) (negativeDouble - 0.5); 

// general case
double unknownDouble = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
int unknownInt = (int) (unknownDouble + (unknownDouble < 0? -0.5 : 0.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print(Math.round(totalCost));
```

Simple

Answer (score 1):

**Math.round()** method in Java returns the closest int or long as per the argument

```
Math.round(0.48) = 0
Math.round(85.6) = 86
```

Similarly,

Math.ceil gives the smallest integer as per the argument.

```
 Math.round(0.48) = 0
 Math.round(85.6) = 85
```

Math.floor gives the largest integer as per the argument.

```
 Math.round(0.48) = 1
 Math.round(85.6) = 86
```